# ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81: Method render does not exist. -- Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I'm trying to do a simple pagination.

It works well on localhost but when hosted online, The following error erupt:

```
ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81: Method render does not exist.
```

In my controller I have:

```
$post=Post::paginate(5);
```

in my view I am calling

```
{!! $post->render() !!}
```

But when `{!! $post->render() !!}` is removed from the view, it will display well online.

Comment: `render()` method is part of LengthAwarePaginator class. So try installing composer packages again after removing "vendor" folder and "composer.lock" file.